# Rank query not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have looked at various SO questions for how to do count and rank.  I have a field in my database called vDestination, and I want to get a count and rank of each destination.  I am using Codeigniter.  I have the following:

```
$sql = ("SET @curRank := 0;\r\n
            SELECT vDestination, COUNT(*) AS count, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM tbl_user_trip ORDER BY vDestination");
```

This looks to me like valid SQL syntax, but I keep getting database errors.  Will someone please point out to me what is wrong with this query?

> A Database Error Occurred
> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT vDestination, COUNT(*) AS count, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM tb' at line 3
>
> ```
> SET @curRank := 0;
> SELECT vDestination, COUNT(*) AS count, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
> FROM tbl_user_trip ORDER BY vDestination
> ```

This is the error I am getting.

Comment: What database errors are you getting. Please include in your question

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: See updated question.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
 $this->db->query("SET @curRank := 0");
 $this->db->query("SELECT vDestination, COUNT(*) AS count, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM tbl_user_trip ORDER BY vDestination");
```

Comment: @Michael Nares Missed that part. I focused on fixing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Working solution is as follows:

```
function getMostPopularDestinations()
    {
        $this->db->query("SET @curRank := 0");
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT vDestination, COUNT(*) AS count, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM tbl_user_trip GROUP BY vDestination ORDER BY vDestination");
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

So as @tyro suggested, but with a GROUP BY as well.